# Google favoring schema.org over meta data?

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets

Google just started indexing my Schema.org-markup - showing prices and ratings for my e-commerce products.

However they also stopped showing my meta-description in the SERP and are instead showing text from the description-property of the Product object.

Does Google generally favor Schema.org-tagged text over meta-tags?

Comment: you should ask yourself: why are product description and page meta-description different? I assume only one possible case: if the product is not the main entity of the page. And this is not correct, if you want to sell it.

Comment: Isn’t your question only about Schema.org’s `description` vs. the `meta`-`description`? As you can’t get rich snippets with Schema.org …

Comment: The main product description (displayed on the page and marked with schema.org) is much longer than the meta-description in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google will always show a preference for information that is displayed over meta information which is not displayed. Your schema markup is for content that is displayed, hence the preference.

Comment: I see, but wouldn't this policy also make Google use the product name (marked using schema.org) over the meta-title, as the title in the SERP? How come Google picked the meta-title in this case, when they discarded the meta-description?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, my client wanted Google to display the `meta-description` since it was shorter (and more to the point) than the product description displayed on the page. So we tried removing the `description` property of the `Product` object. This caused Google to ignore the Product object completely, not showing any price/stock/stars or such in the SERP. So it seems `description` is mandatory, and Google will likely use it in favor of the `meta-description`.